# Solaris 12.3 C++ compiler out of memory

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, solaris-10, solaris-studio

I have a swig generated C++ code file of 24MB, nearly 5,00,000 lines of code. I am able to compile it when set the compiler Optimization level to xO0,but fails as soon as i add any other C++ compiler flags(like xprofile ...). I am using Solaris Studio 12.3 C++ compiler.

Below is the console error:

```
    Element size (in bytes):        48
    Table size (in elements):  2560000
    Table maximum size:        134217727
    Table size increment:         5000
    Bytes written to disk:           0
    Expansions required:             9
    Segments used:                   1
    Max Segments used:               1
    Max Segment offset:        134217727
    Segment offset size::           27
    Resizes made:                    0
    Copies due to expansions:        4
    Reset requests:                  0
    Allocation requests:       2827527
    Deallocation requests:      267537
    Allocated element count:      4086
    Free element count:        2555914
    Unused element count:            0
    Free list size (elements):       0
```

ir2hf: error: Out of memory

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Sorry, my magic wand isn't working, and I doubt anyone else's is either.    Either install more memory on the host machine or (if running in a virtual machine) allocate more to the virtual machine. If a compiler runs out of memory with some options - compilation level is an option - that's a fair sign it needs more memory to work. There aren't generally ways to make a compiler do things with less memory than it needs.   So you're left with making more memory available for it to use.  Either that, or edit the file and create a set of smaller files from it, and compile them separately.

Comment: My crystal ball tells to try this: as root: `usermod -K defaultpriv=basic,sys_resource <userid>`, then as user: `ulimit -d unlimited`

Comment: I don't wan't to make it into smaller files as it is Auto generated file.

Comment: 12.3 is old. IIRC, the tools were still 32-bit at the time, so they couldn't use more than 4G of memory. You may need a more recent compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I found this [article](https://developmentonsolaris.wordpress.com/2008/04/05/data-seg-limit-and-crashing-sun-c-issue/) suggesting that it has to do with the fact that Solaris the amount of memory for data segments.

Following the steps in the blog, try to remove the limit.

```
$ usermod -K defaultpriv=basic,sys_resource karel
```

Now logoff and logon again and change the limit:

```
$ ulimit -d unlimited
```

Then check that the limit has changed

```
$ ulimit -d
```

The output should be `unlimited`

Comment: the memory is already set to "unlimited" still it's not working.

Comment: Are you sure that  you have enough memory on the machine?

Comment: I am working on a Server. It has enough Memory.load averages:                
3.41,  4.07,  4.48                                                                                                                                                               17:00:36
1211 processes:1199 sleeping, 3 zombie, 6 stopped, 3 on cpu
CPU states: 92.2% idle,  3.5% user,  4.3% kernel,  0.0% iowait,  0.0% swap
Memory: 160G real, 41G free, 102G swap in use, 20G swap free

Comment: Ok, looks like plenty of memory. Sorry, don't know how to solve this.